# How to use on premise Git repository with Bluemix?

Tags: git, ibm-cloud

I would like to use an existing, on premise, GIT repository to build and deploy the application on Bluemix instead of the repository which comes with DevOps services or public GitHub. It seems not possible to change the repository URL in the build stage.

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix DevOps [integrates](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/sourcecontrol/) with three three types of repositories at the moment:

1. GitHub.com
2. public or private Git repository that is hosted on Bluemix
3. Jazz SCM

I suggest you to move your on premise GIT repository into private GitHub repository or private git repository hosted on Bluemix.
Configuration of build pipeline from repositories hosted there is seamless.